how to delete or hide specific page of report in stimulsoft?
i want to know is that possible to remove or hide a page programmatically for stimulsoft?
i rather not to use condition and maybe that page already have Datalist.
i just want to force some specific page to remove/hide.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
